# unable to give path to templates in Django

Tags: python, django, frontend, web-development-server

Django question here:
So I was trying to get some html files to work through templates. I put this in the views.py file:

```
def about (request):
    return render(request, 'about.html')

def contact (request):
    return render(request, 'contact.html')

def pricing (request):
    return render(request, 'pricing.html')

def faq (request):
    return render(request, 'faq.html')
```

and this in the urls.py file:

```
 path('about', views.about, name='about'),
    path('contact', views.contact, name='contact'),
    path('pricing', views.pricing, name='pricing'),
    path('faq', views.faq, name='faq'),
]
```

Yet when I try to go there through the home page, it doesn't work and I get this:
[Error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DzzY.png)

Does anyone know how to fix this?!?!!!
My templates folder and manage.py are in the same folder

Answer (score 1):

The urlconf you have is missing slashes at the end of each pattern, but the main issue you have is that your about page is to be accessed by:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/about/
```

Comment: So I should have this:  path('about/', views.about, name='about'),

Comment: Yes. Also you think you can access `about.html` but that's the name of the template file, not the path you declared in your urlconf.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the issue I had was that I was href-ing 'about.html' and not just 'about' in my index.html file

I changed that and it worked!